# What is the square root of $(-5)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, radicals

Is this statement true?

$$\sqrt{(-5)^2} = -5$$

Comment: no it is $5$ since $$(-5)^2=5^2$$

Comment: Basically square root function returns always positive value so answer should be +5.If we find sqrt of x*x it is |x| and not x.

Comment: We usually define $\sqrt{x}$ for $x$ real and positive to be the positive square root. But in some circtumstances, we allow for $\sqrt{x}$ to be a multi-valued function, in which $-5$ is **a value** for $\sqrt{(-5)^2}$.

Comment: Also, I need to complain about your use of tags.  Please read what the tags say to ensure that they mean what you intend.  The tag `Linear algebra` is about the study of vectorspaces and linear operators between them.  The tag `roots` is talking about roots of equations, i.e. those values of $x$ for which $f(x)=0$, for example the roots of $f(x)=(x-2)(x-3)$ are $2$ and $3$ respectively.  Neither have anything to do with your question.  Correct tags would have been things like Algebra-precalculus, Arithmetic, and Radicals.  Do try to use correct tags in the future.

Answer (score 6):

No: The radical sign usually denotes the *non-negative branch* of the square root, so
$$
\sqrt{x^{2}} = |x|\quad\text{ for all real $x$.}
$$
Consequently, $\sqrt{(-5)^{2}} = 5$.

Answer (score 4):

**No** it is not.

You have

$$\sqrt{(-5)^2}=\sqrt{(-5)\times (-5)}=\sqrt{25}=5.$$

Not $-5$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{(-x)^2} = |x|$$

$$(\sqrt{x})^2 = x$$